# Why is this method of establishing a limit relation incorrect?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am studying infinite sequences from Calculus-I by Apostol and came across this exercise: 
$$\text{Prove that} \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} \; \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n+k} = \log\,2$$ I know from another exercise that the way to solve this problem is by equating the limit of this sequence to $ \int_0^1\, \frac{1}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x$.
Can somebody please point out what is the error in the following method: $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \; \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n+k} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \; \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1/n}{1+k/n} = 0$$ Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The fact that summand tends to 0 doesn't mean that the sum tends to 0 too. Besides the limit is over $n$, not $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing,
you are taking the limit
with respect to a variable
($x$)
that is not in the formula.
I assume that
you mean
$\lim_{n \to \infty}$.

Second,
as Alex pointed out,
the limit of the sum
is not necessarily
the sum of the limits.
For a very elementary
example of this,

$$1
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n}
\ne \sum_{k=1}^n \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{n}
= \sum_{k=1}^n 0
=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you. "The limit of the sum is not the sum of the limits" . Is this because an infinite sum is involved?

Comment: Yes. For a finite sum, the concept of limit does not apply. It is when the number of terms can grow arbitrarily large, that strange things can happen.

Comment: Thanks again. This clears things up.